# abstract derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

My group has code with the following structure

```
class Base
{
public:
  float some_base_function(); 
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public: 
  float some_other_function(); 
  float yet_another_function(); 
};
```

which is simple enough. The issue is that I'm currently thinking about reimplementing `Derived` in a few experimental ways. My thinking was to do this:

```
class IDerived : public Base
{ 
public: 
  virtual float some_other_function() = 0; 
  virtual float yet_another_function() = 0; 
};
```

And then change the old `Derived` to inherit from `IDerived`. Is this sort of Concrete --> Abstract --> Concrete inheritance structure even allowed in C++?

To make matters worse, the original `Derived` class is persistified within the framework, so it must maintain the same structure in memory (which I hoped to achieve by making `IDerived` abstract). Will the new `Derived` have the same memory layout?

Comment: Your last paragraph is very worrying. I find it hard to imagine a well designed C++ framework requiring a specific memory structure for the objects that it operates on. Are you sure that you are using the framework correctly?

Comment: What benefit do you gain from this?

Comment: @Mankarse, The framework is _not_ well designed, that's way I'm asking such a strange question. But such is life, sometimes frameworks are designed by people who don't know what they are doing.

Comment: What about creating additional abstract class (interface) with some_other_function = 0 and yet_another_function = 0 and using multiple inheritance: from Base and this interface?

Comment: @AlexFarber, interesting idea, I wasn't sure if it was cleaner to use multiple inheritance or multiple generations of inheritance, but if there is a clear advantage to your suggestion I'd be all for that.

Comment: Out of interest, do you need to mix and match different implementations at runtime, or are you just trying to test some alternative versions of the same two methods?

Comment: I need both implementations for now: the one that is persistified and the one that I'm modifying. It's possible to edit the persistence code if the memory structure won't match up, although it's less than ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's legal, but it doesn't seem like you need that. What's the point of the extra inheritance?

Moreover, `Base` and `Derived` don't have any virtual methods, so by adding any you can be 99% sure the memory layout won't be the same.

Comment: I'm in the process of rewriting `Derived`, but it's created in several places and stored in an container with the other `Base` objects. I'm hoping I can replace some of the `Derived` objects but not all of them.

Comment: The memory layout of `Derived` will definitely change if neither it nor `Base` had any virtual methods or inheritance before.

Comment: @Useless can you quote the standard on that?

Comment: Nope - I should say it _will probably change in many common implementations_.  But you should definitely assume the compiler is free to change the layout.

Comment: @Useless completely agree - that's why I said 99%

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to disabuse OP of what seemed like a very slender hope

Comment: thanks, our framework is full of those 1% coincidences where things just magically work (to the point that most people are afraid to breathe on it the wrong way), but I would prefer something more robust, so I'll probably look into fixing the persistence code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is allowed.  But general practice is to avoid concrete base classes of any sort (see e.g. Item 33 of Scott Meyers' [*More Effective C++*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/More-Effective-Programs-Professional-Computing/dp/020163371X/)).

Attempting to persist complex objects by storing their binary representation is bound to lead to all sorts of problems; I would suggest finding a better mechanism (serialization, etc.).

Comment: sure, but this is a group framework that won't change any time soon, so unfortunately I have to work with the concrete base class for now